# Slideshow auto play - Jquery "Flipping Circle Slideshow"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autoplay

I'm reading a tutorial about how create a Flipping Circle Slideshow.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/28/flipping-circle-slideshow/comment-page-2/

everything is great but i would like to run the Slideshow on auto play This is the code I'm using but don't run well I received this code from the tutorial before you initialise the plugin, eg `$(element).flipshow()`; you can add a public method named navigate and then call it from within a `setInterval` function.

```
$.Flipshow.prototype.navigate=function(element,direction){
     this._navigate(element,direction);
};

$("#fcSlideshow").flipshow();

setInterval( function() {
     $('#fcSlideshow').flipshow('navigate',$("#fcSlideshow div.fc-right span:first"),'right');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Have you changed your html as well to use `<div id="#fcSlideshow"` instead of `<div id="fc-slideshow"`? I have just tested and it's working fine.

Comment: Morpheus Thank you very much !!!!!! now is running perfectly